# Directory file listing sorted in output :(

Tags: sorting, python-2.7, xml-parsing, directory

I have a list of xml files in a directory for example:

```
file1.xml
file2.xml 
file3.xml
file4.xml
file5.xml
file10.xml
file11.xml
file12.xml
file22.xml
file23.xml
file24.xml
file31.xml
file32.xml
file33.xml
```

When I use os.listdir(path) and print the file names, the output is as follows:

```
file1.xml
file10.xml 
file11.xml
file12.xml
file2.xml
file22.xml
file23.xml
file24.xml
file3.xml
file31.xml
file32.xml
file33.xml
file4.xml
file5.xml
```

Expected Outptut

```
file1.xml
file2.xml 
file3.xml
file4.xml
file5.xml
file10.xml
file11.xml
file12.xml
file22.xml
file23.xml
file24.xml
file31.xml
file32.xml
file33.xml
```

Can any1 tell me if there is a solution for this problem. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the docs for [os.listdir](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) (emphasis mine):

**os.listdir(path)**

> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory
>   given by path. *The list is in arbitrary order*. It does not include the
>   special entries '.' and    '..' even if they are present in the
>   directory.

Given your example, perhaps the easiest way is to sort the list by extracting the numbers from the name, and sorting by those:

```
import os, re

filenames = os.listdir('/path/to/your/files')
filenames.sort(key=lambda L: map(int, re.findall('\d+', L)))
```

Comment: hey @Jon Clements  could you please brief me the working of this line filenames.sort(key=lambda L: map(int, re.findall('\d+', L)))

Comment: @Sangamesh it finds all the consecutive digits in the string using a regular expression (`\d+`), converts them to integers, and uses those as the key to the sort method

Comment: Thank you so much for the inforamtion i really appreciate it:) keep rocking!